# Module or Library for Python speech to text (2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, speech-to-text

So i have been searching for a speech to text module, and i have found a few, such as dragonfly and pyspeech, however, they are for python 2.4 and 2.5, however, i need one for 2.7. Does anyone know of a library or module for this? Thank you in advance for your replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a speech0.5.2 distribution for py2.7 in the [Base package from Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).
The Base package has been recently prepared also for py3k (same link) but I'm not sure if speech is included.

Comment: Is there any way to get that package without the Base package?

Comment: I think so. From the website: "These installers are valid ZIP files, which allow to manually extract single module files or package directories of interest."

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also use python bindings for speech recognition engines like,[pocketsphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx) and [cmusphinx3](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) ( eg; [python-pocketsphinx](http://maemo.org/packages/view/python-pocketsphinx/) and cmusphinx3-python )

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation: [Dragonfly requires python 2.5 or later.](http://pythonhosted.org/dragonfly/installation.html#installation). Python 2.7 is OK for Dragonfly.

Answer (score 0):

dragonfly 0.6.5 works on py2.7 if you have package manager installed just:
press: <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>;
press: <kbd>CMD</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd>;
type: `pip install dragonfly`

check if is installed by typing: pip list (it will show you all installed packages)